# implementing piped xargs rm and tee command into python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix

I have a python script that prints out file names according to specific wildcard patterns and characteristics. I then pipe a few commands to this printed out list, with `xargs rm` removing the listed files. This script is run on a unix server and ordinarily, I would run the script as follows:

`python deletefiles.py <directory> <wildcard1> | tee deletedfiles.txt | xargs rm`

this runs fine and all, but I am trying to find a way so that the `tee` and `xargs rm` command are in the script already so that the user doesn't have to type it into the command.

i've looked online and people say to `import subprocess`, but i don't understand the full syntax of how to use it in junction with my script.

as of right now, the code to run on a unix system is simply

```
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    try:
        input_directory = sys.argv[1]
        input_delete = sys.argv[2].split(',') \\patterns to delete
    except ValueError:
        "Please enter a valid input"
```

what i am trying to do is implement a check for another argument, analyze/delete, where `analyze` just lets the script do it's job of printing out the file names and if the argument is `delete`, the script will `xargs rm` and `tee` those files.

I'm not sure as to how to even approach this, as a large point of printing the files with my python script was so that `xargs rm` and `tee deletedfiles.txt` has something to go off of when deleting/saving to a text file. i was wondering if there was a way to do this conditionally within a python script

if i need to provide any more information regarding my script, i am happy to oblige

Answer (score 0):

You could run them as a subprocess. There is a better alternative, though; see below.

Assuming `files` contains your file names,

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen("tee '{0}' | xargs rm".format(teefile),
    shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate('\n'.join(files))
```

However, both operations are trivial to do in Python natively.

```
with open(teefile, "w") as tee:
    for file in files:
        tee.write(file + '\n')
        os.unlink(file)
```

I think you'll agree that the latter is simpler and more elegant (though in Python 3 the `subprocess` can also be made much simpler; you really want to prepare to switch to Python 3 ASAP.)

Answer (score -1):

I was originally going to just make a comment, but I think this is easier to understand.

Python has a module called [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) to handle command line arguments. The examples are a little confusing, so I'd recommend just staring at `get_args` below till it makes sense.

Instead of trying to pipe it to `tee` and `xargs rm`, you can do all of this within the python script itself.

Heres an example that you can build off of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

# allows us to use python3 print function
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import fnmatch
import sys
import argparse


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # note directory has `required=True`, that means the user must provide it
    parser.add_argument("--directory", help="Directory to analyze", required=True)
    # store_true stores a boolean depending on whether or not the flag was present
    parser.add_argument("--delete", help="Delete the files which should be removed", action="store_true", default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args() # parses, makes sure all conditions are met, exits if user didn't provide a filename
    return args


def analyze(directory):
    # do whatever wildcarding here to return a list of files
    # heres just an example, remove all *.txt files recursively
    files_to_delete = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        # fnmatch is unix-like filename matching
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "*.txt"):
            # abspath gives us the full path, root is the original directory
            files_to_delete.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)))
    return files_to_delete


def delete(files):
    # write to deleted_files.txt in this function
    deleted_file = open("deleted_files.txt", 'w')
    for f in files:
        if os.path.exists(f): # filepath exists
            if os.path.isfile(f): # is a file (not a directory)
                os.remove(f) # remove it
                deleted_file.write("{}\n".format(f)) # write to the file
            else:
                print("Could not remove {}, is not a file".format(f), file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print("Could not remove {}, does not exist".format(f), file=sys.stderr)
    deleted_file.close()


def main():
    args = get_args()
    files = analyze(args.directory)
    # if the user gave us the --delete flag
    if args.delete:
        delete(files)
    else:
        # just print it out to the user
        for f in files:
            print(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you just wanted to save which files should be deleted, redirect the output to a file

`python2.7 deletefiles.py --directory test_dir > files_to_delete.txt`

If you wanted to delete them:

`python2.7 deletefiles.py --directory test_dir --delete`

and then you can `cat deleted_files.txt` to get the files that were deleted.

Heres some documentation for functions I used:

[`fnmatch.filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter), [`sys.stderr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stderr), [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile), [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove)

If you wanted to remove directories, take a look at [`os.removedirs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.removedirs)

Comment: definitely something i'll look into implementing, and if it works i'll mark it as solved. thank you!

Comment: Let me know if something doesnt work and I'll see what I can do